# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Room without an ID):と表示されメッセージの送信ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

現在、[【Rails6】（送信時のリロード無し！）Action CableでSlack風チャットアプリを作成-Qiita](https://qiita.com/take18k_tech/items/00cc14c0eff45073ffc7)の記事を参考にしActionCableを使用し、非同期通信のチャット機能を実装しており、チャットルームの作成はできたのですが、その作成したチャットルームでメッセージを送信した際にブラウザ上には何も変化がなく、ターミナル上に以下のエラーメッセージが出てきてしまいます。

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2020-08-27 10:52:46 +0900
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2020-08-27 10:52:46 +0900
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
RoomChannel is streaming from room_channel
Started POST "/messages" for ::1 at 2020-08-27 10:52:51 +0900
Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ec4H5uZQoum7g7pxCtzZ54ahkYtevZTPG4uKsFa2IqEC70mnmsxOzX6mpq+tYPFLJMLHbhXOBCnGdcVGF+4tZw==", "message"=>{"content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"送信"}
  User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms | Allocations: 2232)


  
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Room without an ID):
  
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

RoomIDがないと表示されてしまっているので。(params[:room_id])をコントローラーに追加したのですが、特に表示も変わらず何が原因かがわからない状態です。

Messagesコントローラー

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @message = Message.new
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
    @messages = @room.messages.includes(:user)
  end
  
  def create
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
    @message = @room.messages.create!(message_params)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', message: @message.content
  end

  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Roomsコントローラー

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @rooms = Room.all.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

  def create
    @room = Room.new(room_params)
    if @room.save
      redirect_to rooms_path
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def show
    @messages = Message.all.includes(:user).order(:id)
    @message = current_user.messages.build
  end

  private

  def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(:name, user_ids:[])
  end
end
```

Messagesコントローラーのdef createの下にbinding.pryをかけ、その結果は以下の通りです。

```
**[1] pry(#<MessagesController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"meX+mFWTSwDSkuxI2lP5e99s1PW3JCSIKchiFRDiWyvixLDZKQ+nJBe38JZ979HXfQ+CEPxXtG70Ni3jUbpU7Q==", "message"=>{"content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"送信", "controller"=>"messages", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
[2] pry(#<MessagesController>)> @message
=> nil
[3] pry(#<MessagesController>)> **
```

初学者のため拙い説明でわかりづらい点やこちらの理解不足も多くあると思います。
どなたかお力添え頂けますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: room_idがparamsに含まれていないようです。まずは、`params[:room_id]` に期待した値が入るところまでを目指すのがよいと思います。なので、おそらく回答にはView側のソースも必要そうです。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishiさん、コメントありがとうございます。[:room_id]をどうparamsに含めようかと試行錯誤をしていて、route設定でroomとmessageをネストし、messageコントローラーのストロングパラメーターのmergeでroom_id: params[:room_id]を追加しました。ですが、roomのshowページに遷移しようとした際に[No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages", :id=>"11"}, missing required keys: [:room_id]」と追加でエラーが出てきてしまいました。そもそものやり方が間違えているんでしょうか...。

Comment: 参考にしているページへのリンクを追加したほうが、回答が集まりやすそうに思います　paramsのくだりがあったので、room_idについて言及してしまいましたが、そもそも room_id が必要かどうか現時点ではわかりませんね（ひとつの可能性でしかないですね）。

Comment: 色々試したことを掲載していただくのはとても重要なことと思いますが、間違った方向に進んでいると、解決のしようがないので、まずはじめにエラーに遭遇したときのコードも載せていただけると回答がつきやすいと考えます。（いまは色々やっているときのコードしか掲載されていないと思います）

Comment: https://github.com/T-Tsujii/chat_app サンプルコードがあるようなので、こちらをまず試してみて違いを確認してみるのはいかがでしょうか